# Add details to Bubble Chart from phuonghuynh

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

The bubble chart from phuonghuynh (http://bl.ocks.org/phuonghuynh/54a2f97950feadb45b07) is visually really appealing but it is missing some details for the big central bubble. Does somebody know how to add details to the big bubble?

The javascript looks like this:

```
data: {
        items: [
            {text: "Java", count: "236"},
            {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
            {text: "Php", count: "170"},
            {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
            {text: "D", count: "12"},
            {text: "Python", count: "170"},
            {text: "C/C++", count: "382"},
            {text: "Pascal", count: "10"},
            {text: "Something", count: "170"},
        ],
        eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
        classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
    },
    plugins: [
        {
            name: "central-click",
            options: {
                text: "(See more detail)",
                style: {
                    "font-size": "12px",
                    "font-style": "italic",
                    "font-family": "Source Sans Pro, sans-serif",
                    //"font-weight": "700",
                    "text-anchor": "middle",
                    "fill": "white"
                },
                attr: {dy: "65px"},
                centralClick: function() {
                    alert("Mehr Infos");
                }
            }
        },
```

I would like to add some additional information to every bubble but only showing up when the big bubble is clicked.

Comment: Did you try any coding yourself?

Comment: Just add the code to add the additional information to every bubble in your `centralClick` function.